# Running a php script from cron not picking the $_SERVER['host'] wheras running from CLI works

Tags: php, linux, cron, centos, command-line-interface

As stated, when I run a direct PHP script like so:

```
# /usr/bin/php path/to/script.php
```

I am able to use environment variables

But when I have this script running from cron:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php path/to/script.php
```

The script runs but all my environment variables are null.

How do I simulate the CLI via the cron?

(on centOS / linux)

Comment: maybe a stupid idea but with php 5.4 it should be easy to use the buildin development webserver for such use cases http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a script which sets the environment variables you want to be present:

```
#!/bin/bash

export ENV_VAR_ONE="value one"
export ENV_VAR_TWO="value two"
/usr/bin/php path/to/script.php
```

and then invoke that script from cron instead.

Comment: thanks for this. is there a way for me to detect, in my bash script, what php refers to as $_SERVER['HOSTNAME'] ? Is there a bash environment variable that returns the same thing?

Comment: nevermind my last question. The variable in the shell script is $(hostname)